# Javascript Date/Time Format

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format

I put a clock on a web page and I need to format it as shown below :

```
Wednesday 29 March 2016 12:01:11
```

So that the seconds will be changing. I have done this as shown below :

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myFunction() }, 1000)

var dayName = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();

    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getUTCMonth();
    var date = d.getUTCDate();
    var day = d.getUTCDay();

    var hours = d.getHours();
    if(hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var secs = d.getSeconds();
    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
    }

    var fullDateTime = dayName[day] + " " +  date + " " + monthName[month] + " " + year + " " + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

    document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = fullDateTime;

}
```

I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toLocaleString instead of assigning the days and months in array. I have modified a bit your code.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myFunction() }, 1000)

function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var locale = "en-us";

    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
    var date = d.getUTCDate();
    var day = d.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" });

    var hours = d.getHours();
    if(hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;

        var mins = d.getMinutes();
    if (mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;

        var secs = d.getSeconds();
    if (secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;

    var fullDateTime = day + " " +  date + " " + month + " " + year + " " + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

    document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = fullDateTime;

}
```

Find the output in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8r22em5/).

Comment: Be wary of browser support however [IE 11 and up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#compat-desktop)

Answer (score -1):

Use this library http://momentjs.com/

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myFunction() }, 1000)
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = moment().format('dddd Do MMMM HH:mm:ss');
}
```